# Show and Hide UIView on swipe without IF statement?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have the following code to scroll through UIViews on swipe.

My question is, is there a better way of running through each of the views rather than having an if statement?
As I feel the will get even bigger if I add any more view layers.

Or is there a way of me getting the current views id/model/IBOutlet as I feel I could resolve the issue with this.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var WalkthroughScreen1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var WalkthroughScreen2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var WalkthroughScreen3: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var WalkthroughScreen4: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        WalkthroughScreen1.isHidden = false
        WalkthroughScreen2.isHidden = true
        WalkthroughScreen3.isHidden = true
        WalkthroughScreen4.isHidden = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func SwipeLeft(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if WalkthroughScreen1.isHidden == false {
            WalkthroughScreen1.isHidden = true
            WalkthroughScreen2.isHidden = false
        } else {
            if WalkthroughScreen2.isHidden == false {
                WalkthroughScreen2.isHidden = true
                WalkthroughScreen3.isHidden = false
            } else {
                if WalkthroughScreen3.isHidden == false {
                    WalkthroughScreen3.isHidden = true
                    WalkthroughScreen4.isHidden = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func SwipeRight(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if WalkthroughScreen4.isHidden == false {
            WalkthroughScreen4.isHidden = true
            WalkthroughScreen3.isHidden = false
        } else {
            if WalkthroughScreen3.isHidden == false {
                WalkthroughScreen3.isHidden = true
                WalkthroughScreen2.isHidden = false
            } else {
                if WalkthroughScreen2.isHidden == false {
                    WalkthroughScreen2.isHidden = true
                    WalkthroughScreen1.isHidden = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: For walkthrough screen why don't you use a `UICollectionView` with four cells and vertical scrolling or `UIScrollView` with page indicator and paging enabled.

Comment: Cant you use a tableview or a collection view and remove the particular cell from the table when swiping right?

Comment: I was hoping to keep some of the elements on the page, in my view there are images, text and buttons.
I need the buttons to stay in place but only change the images and text content.

Comment: You can achieve that too by adding button as a subview to the main view and keeping it in front with proper constraints.

Comment: Would this still not require me to have if statements when needing to remove elements? I would really like to do the properly, if anybody can provide a link to a tutorial showing the above with CollectionView, ScrollView or TableView, or an example. that would be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

When creating components and numbering them with number to indicate the differences, you should use an array. This is what I should do:

1. Remove all the outlets
2. Create an IBOutletCollection with your views, and tag your views to indicate the hierarchy
3. Sort that IBOutletCollection in your viewDidLoad, so that the tag with the lowest value become first, and the tag with the biggest value become last. This is needed because the order of an IBOutletCollection is NOT sorted and can change, despite what other people say.
4. Change your swipeLeft method to something like this ( I do not have a compiler here so I may make some errors):

code:

```
guard let index = walkthroughScreens.index { !$0.hidden } else { return } // This gets the non-hidden walkthroughScreen
walkthroughScreens[index].isHidden = true
walkthroughScreens[index + 1].isHidden = false // <- make sure index isn't out of bounds.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (might contain slight syntax errors, don't have Xcode currently available):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var WalkthroughScreen1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var WalkthroughScreen2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var WalkthroughScreen3: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var WalkthroughScreen4: UIView!
    weak var screens:[UIView]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        screens = [WalkthroughScreen1, WalkthroughScreen2, WalkthroughScreen3, WalkthroughScreen4]
        WalkthroughScreen1.isHidden = false
        WalkthroughScreen2.isHidden = true
        WalkthroughScreen3.isHidden = true
        WalkthroughScreen4.isHidden = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func SwipeLeft(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if let nextInx = screens.index(of: sender.view)+1 {
            if (nextInx) < screens.count {
                sender.view.isHidden = true
                screens[nextInx].isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func SwipeRight(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if let nextInx = screens.index(of: sender.view)-1 {
            if (nextInx) > 0 {
                sender.view.isHidden = true
                screens[nextInx].isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use design widgets, controllers etc to make an interactive UI so for your question better solution would be use UIPageControl.

@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
@IBOutlet weak var mainScrl: UIScrollView!
let arrImages = [“1.png”, "2.png", "3.png”]// No. of images or you can use your views with  

func loadScrollView() {
let pageCount : CGFloat = CGFloat(arrImages.count)

mainScrl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
mainScrl.delegate = self
mainScrl.pagingEnabled = true
mainScrl.contentSize = CGSizeMake(mainScrl.frame.size.width * pageCount, mainScrl.frame.size.height)
mainScrl.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

pageControl.numberOfPages = Int(pageCount)
pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pageChanged), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

for i in 0..<Int(pageCount) {
print(self. mainScrl.frame.size.width)
let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(self. mainScrl.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i), 0, self.mainScrl.frame.size.width, self.mainScrl.frame.size.height))
image.image = UIImage(named: arrImages[i])!
image.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
self.mainScrl.addSubview(image)
}
}

//MARK: UIScrollView Delegate
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
let viewWidth: CGFloat = scrollView.frame.size.width
// content offset - tells by how much the scroll view has scrolled.
let pageNumber = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - viewWidth / 50) / viewWidth) + 1
pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}


//MARK: Page tap action
func pageChanged() {
let pageNumber = pageControl.currentPage
var frame = scrMain.frame
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(pageNumber)
frame.origin.y = 0
scrMain.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't find the solution on internet but below code can give you an idea about how to implement it using `UICollectionView`:

Create a `UIViewcontroller` with `UICollectionView` as a subview with all four constraints with zero value.

In your `UIViewcontroller` add below codes:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let arrayTitle = ["Hi", "Hello", "Ok", "Got it"]

    let arrayColors = [UIColor.red,UIColor.blue,UIColor.black,UIColor.gray]

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.collectionView!.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: collectionView.frame.size.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

        cell.labelTitle.text = arrayTitle[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = arrayColors[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    } 
}
```

Create a `CustomCollectionViewCell` and add these lines of code:

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelTitle: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

}
```

Hope you will get an idea about how to implement this. I think you can handle the storyboarding by yourself. 
If you have any query regarding Storyboard, UI implementation and constraints feel free to ask.